# Symfony - how to save a xml file?

Tags: symfony

In this code below I have just generated in the browser a .xml page that shows a specific sitemap of the distributor route.

I just want to save this generated .xml in a file (in /public/sitemap folder).

what I have, and what **I WANT TO USE**, are only this two (*like the render at the bottom of the Controller*):

- the urls array (*see: inside the foreach*)
- the template of the xml file

I have already found a possible solution but **is not pratical**, and **is not what I want**. ([Create new xml file and save in system using symfony2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175416/create-new-xml-file-and-save-in-system-using-symfony2-8))

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/sitemap/sitemap.xml", name="distributor_sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})
 */
public function getSitemap(Request $request) : Response
{
    $urls = [];
    $hostname = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

    // return an array of routes
    $routes = $this->sitemapService->getThreeRoutesByIndexes('/distributor/');

    foreach ($routes as $route){

        $urls[] = array('loc' => $this->generateUrl($route));
    }


    // save locally the file

    // -----------------------------
    // ----- add the code HERE -----
    // -----------------------------


    // return response in XML format
    $response = new Response(
        $this->renderView('sitemap/sitemap.html.twig', array(
            'urls' => $urls,
            'hostname' => $hostname
        ))
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
}
```

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

{% for url in urls %}
    <url>{# check if hostname is not alreay in url#}
        <loc>{%if url.loc|replace({hostname:''}) == url.loc%}{{hostname}}{{url.loc}}{%else%}{{url.loc}}{%endif%}</loc>
        {% if url.lastmod is defined %}
            <lastmod>{{url.lastmod}}</lastmod>
        {% endif %}
        {% if url.changefreq is defined %}
            <changefreq>{{url.changefreq}}</changefreq>
        {% endif %}
        {% if url.priority is defined %}
            <priority>{{url.priority}}</priority>
        {% endif %}
        {% if url.image is defined and url.image is not empty %}
            <image:image>
                <image:loc>{%if url.image.loc|replace({hostname:''}) == url.image.loc%}{{hostname}}{{url.image.loc}}{%else%}{{url.image.loc}}{%endif%}</image:loc>
                <image:title>{{ url.image.title }}</image:title>
            </image:image>
        {% endif %}
    </url>
{% endfor %}
```

The Browser result
[image: Browser result]

So again the final result is to generate a .xml file in the /public/sitemap folder, and this file must contain the urls array informations disposed by the template, as it is showed in the browser. ( all the code that to this should be added in the Controller near the `---- add the code HERE ----`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956660/how-to-render-twig-output-to-a-variable-for-later-use-symfony2

Comment: What exactly have you tried to get this done? Why not read Twig's output and write it to a file?

Comment: I don't see a reason to use Twig for this. Just use PHP SimpleXML to generate the XML, then output the result as a response in XML MIME format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign the content of your render template to a var, then write it in the file you want.

```
/**
 * @Route("/sitemap/sitemap.xml", name="distributor_sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})
 */
public function getSitemap(Request $request) : Response
{
    $urls = [];
    $hostname = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

    // return an array of routes
    $routes = $this->sitemapService->getThreeRoutesByIndexes('/distributor/');

    foreach ($routes as $route){

        $urls[] = array('loc' => $this->generateUrl($route));
    }


    // save locally the file
    $xmlContent = $this->renderView('sitemap/sitemap.html.twig', array(
            'urls' => $urls,
            'hostname' => $hostname
        ));
    // Assuming the folder sitemap exists in `public`
    $path = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/sitemap/sitemap.xml';
    $fileSystem = new Filesystem();
    $fileSystem->dumpFile($path, $xmlContent);

    
    // -----------------------------
    // ----- add the code HERE -----
    // -----------------------------


    // return response in XML format
    $response = new Response($xmlContent);
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Why read the container within that controller, instead of injecting the proper path? Why use `file_put_contents` instead of Symfony's abstractions (this could help to make the code testable)?